# Localhost API Call from my xamarin forms app works on emulator but not on my Android device

Tags: android, xamarin, networking, localhost, ip-address

I'm using HttpClient in my Xamarin Forms project to call my Asp.net core REST Api with Base address: https://10.0.2.2:portNumber and everything works fine on the Emulator.

However when I test on my Android device it doesn't work and I don't even get any error. I tried changing the base address to my computer's IPv4 and disabling firewall like it was suggested in here [How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device).
Still nothing seems to work.

I would really appreciate a help here. Thanks

Comment: IP of your computer should work. 10.0.2.2 is only for when running in emulator. Have you checked debug output? Must be saying something is wrong somewhere. If you try the IP from the browser on your device, does that work?

Comment: I don't get any output, It's as if it is taking very long time to load or an endless loop. Just nothing happens after i call the HttpClient.GetAsync(uri).
On the browser I get: "This site can't be reached. 192.168.xxx.xx:44313/ refused to connect" The API is running on https://localhost:44313

Comment: Most definitely networking issues. Nothing to do with android or xamarin.

Comment: maybe I am completely off but I have tried this https://github.com/icflorescu/iisexpress-proxy.. set my local address and then I used my phone and it worked.. Maybe completely different issue. Just a suggestion as I was facing similar issue

Comment: I will give it a try. Nothing else is working anyway.. Thanks

Comment: Could it work now ?Does the rest api require to use a specific port and if yes is that port open in the firewall of the server?

Comment: No, unfortunately  it still doesn't work.
Ye, it does use a specific port which is 44313. what do you mean with open in the firewall of the server or how can i open it if it's not?

Comment: Maybe you could look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365046/get-xamarin-android-device-calling-asp-net-web-api-running-localhost).